# How do I pre-select the value that has been selected for an existing object in SimpleForm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using SimpleForm and I have an input that looks like this:

```
<%= f.input_field :language, collection: Rouge::Lexer.all.map(&:tag).sort, as: :select, selected: "ruby", class: "form-control" %>
```

That stores an object like this:

```
[60] pry(main)> q.language
=> "ruby"
[64] pry(main)> w.language
=> "csharp"
```

This works for new questions, because it auto-selects "ruby" which is good.

However, when the user goes to edit the record, I would like this field to pre-select the language that is stored in this object.

So for the object `q` above, it should preselect "ruby", but for the `w` object it would preselect "csharp".

How do I do that, given that `language` is a string and not an ID, and given that I want a default value for `new` instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

```
selected: @question.language || 'ruby'
```

It will first check if property exists on the model, if not will default to `'ruby'`.

If you want to move this logic out of the template, some good candidate places would be model, presenter or [form object](https://github.com/apotonick/reform).

Comment: Perfect. This is just what I was looking for. Thanks!